# AS3: Where are nonstatic properties stored?

Tags: actionscript-3

My question is efficiency-wise.

Let's assume I have a class `foo` with a complicated nonstatic function called `bar`.

Does having a particularly complex nonstatic function slow down the instantiation of my class? I have read a bit about the presence, in AS3, of an object's prototype, and I guess the explanation will be related.

All in all, what I'm asking is: If I have several instances of `foo`, does each instance actually contain the `bar` property, or is `bar` stored in the prototype?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actionscript is prototype based like javascript. And yes, the bytecode from your function is only stored once.

[image: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/images/op_class_objec_a_popup.png]